# Oracle PL SQL, dynamic synonym feasible (parameterizing schema/table names)?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic, plsql, synonym

Is it possible to parameterize schema and table names used in queries within stored procedures using dynamic synonyms?

What we have tried is

1. setting parameters in a name/value pair table
2. reading those parameters at run time to determine schema (and table names), as the targets change based on the mode of the
   application
3. dropping any existing synonym and recreating for the schema and tables
4. referencing the synonyms in the queries

The reason we are attempting this approach is because the queries to be executed are merge statements that are hundreds of lines long, not suited for dynamic SQL.

Comment: That's a tricky question. If you drop a synonym, all stored procedures that use the synonym will be invalidated. If you haven't used that procedure in the current session yet, it shouldn't be a problem. It will be recompiled when you access it the next time. If you have used it already, you will run into an error message. So it's probably doable if you take additional precautions and properly manage your sessions.

Comment: There is no reason to have only short statements for dynamic SQL, you an use even CLOB for `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. With `DBMS_SQL.VARCHAR2A` it is quite simple to compose big SQL statements.

Comment: Yes, you can but it is not the optimum solution in terms of ease of maintenance.  If you create your statement dynamically and use the oracle built ins then at least all the code is in one place. By creating synonyms this could cause issues of name collision, security and the unfortunate side effect of one mistake causes the wrong thing to be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can cover your problem when you use Invoker Rights for your procedure. Have a look at this example:

```
CREATE USER SCOTT_1 IDENTIFIED BY "tiger";
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO SCOTT_1;

CREATE USER SCOTT_2 IDENTIFIED BY "tiger";
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO SCOTT_2;

CREATE TABLE SCOTT_1.EMP (EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(30));
CREATE TABLE SCOTT_2.EMP (EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(30));

INSERT INTO SCOTT_1.EMP VALUES ('Schema 1');
INSERT INTO SCOTT_2.EMP VALUES ('Schema 2');
COMMIT;

CREATE SYNONYM EMP FOR SCOTT_1.EMP; -- Just needed to compile the procedure

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetSchema(p_schema IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 
   AUTHID CURRENT_USER 
AS
    res VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ' || p_schema;
    SELECT EMP_NAME
    INTO res
    FROM EMP;

    -- Just switch back to own schema to avoid unexpected behaviors
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = '||USER;

    RETURN res;
END;
/


SELECT GetSchema('SCOTT_1') FROM dual;

GETSCHEMA('SCOTT_1') 
---------------------------------
Schema 1

1 row selected.


SELECT GetSchema('SCOTT_2') FROM dual;

GETSCHEMA('SCOTT_2')          
---------------------------------
Schema 2

1 row selected.
```